# How to bind one key to press multiple keys with karabiner elements

Tags: keybindings, karabiner

I've been trying to bind my <kbd>X</kbd> button to do left click, <kbd>A</kbd>, and <kbd>W</kbd> for the past few days. I've tried using all sorts of attempts and changing code of other's JSON files multiple times, but it hasn't been working.

This is some code I attempted to use, but it wouldn't even show up in the complex modifications

```
"rules": [
    {  "description": "Call it whatever you like…",
       "manipulators": [ {
                "type": "basic",
                "from": {
                    "key_code": “x”,
              },
              "to": [
                      {“key_code": “button1”},
                      {“key_code": “a”},
                      {“key_code": “w”,
                          “repeat”: true }
              ]
          }]
```